# Remove nodes in a new variable without affecting the original variable (Networkx)

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

l'm using `networkx` to generate random graphs.

My process is as follow:

from an initial graph G, let's say  :

```
 G = nx.watts_strogatz_graph(100, 2, 0)
```

l would like to generate 40 other graphs such that the generated graphs contains less nodes than the original graph.

At each iteration, l set the number of nodes to remove and the index of nodes.

**What l have tried ?**

G = nx.watts_strogatz_graph(100, 2, 0) # is the original graph from which l generate other graphs

number_examples=40

```
for i in np.arange(examples):
        F = randint(1, 5) # to get the number of nodes to remove for the example i

        nodes_remove = sample(range(0, len(G.nodes())), F)# return the indexes of nodes to be removed
        L=G # L will be the new graph, G is the initial graph 
        L.remove_nodes_from(nodes_remove)
        number_nodes.append(len(L.nodes()))
        print('number of nodes in the new graph L ', len(L.nodes())
        print('number of nodes in the initial graph G ', len(G.nodes())
```

**Wrong output ?**
Yes output of L is correct since l remove nodes. However G should remain the same `len(G.nodes())=100`, since l set `L=G`, l make changes only on **L**

However each time l remove nodes in L , G to do the same.

**Expected output ?**

For the original graph **G= 100 nodes**

l generate lets say five graphs **L1, L2,L3,L4,L5** from the original graph **G** :

```
L1= 97 nodes
L2= 98 nodes
L3= 95 nodes
L4= 99 nodes
L5=97 nodes
```

**these are the expected outputs**

However l get :

```
L1= 97 nodes
L2= 95 nodes
L3= 90 nodes
L4= 89 nodes
L5=86 nodes
```

which means at it iteration we remove nodes from the new graph generated.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in the [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.copy.html):

```
L = G.copy()
```

This makes a complete copy of the graph including all of the node or edge attributes.

Comment: [Documentation of the latest stable version](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.copy.html)